# Console logging does not work in Pivotal TC server of STS 3.6.4.RELEASE

Tags: logback, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I upgraded to STS 3.6.4.RELEASE and found the console logging does not work. On further research this is what I found

These VM arguments were added in TC server.

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager 

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/testmac/Work/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/logging.properties
```

Even if I remove the above arguments and apply the changes, they are generated back, so I am basically forced to use them.

So after going thru http://static.springsource.com/projects/tc-server/6.0/admin/cadmlogging.html , I looked into **pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/conf/logging.properties** as defined in generated VM arguments, where I added this..

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFromatter
```

The above changes to the logging.properties do not work as well, all the **org.springframework** related logs are vanished. All I see is few logback related logs in console.

Upon reverting to previous version of STS console logging works fine.

**NOTE:** We are using logback and I do see in console that it read logback.xml defined in the class path..

```
13:46:09,154 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/Users/bhitstestmac/Work/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.0.RELEASE/base-instance/wtpwebapps/consent2share-web-bl/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
```

How can I tell TC server to stdout all org.springframework related console logs? This is stopping us from upgrading to STS 3.6.4.RELEASE, and we have experienced this both in Mac and PC.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you mistyped in your config, but it should be SimpleFormatter

> java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFromatter

Also did you add the ConsoleHandler to the rootLogger?

```
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```